# Expressing two sums as a single sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

For this question, I need to express these two sums as a single sum. Here is what I have so far. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, can anyone please help me?

$$ \Biggl(3\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} (k^2-1)\Biggl) + \Biggl(5\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n} (k-n)^2+1\Biggl)$$

$$ =  \Biggl(3\sum \limits_{k=n+1}^{2n} (k^2-1)+n\Biggl) + \Biggl(5\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n} (k-n)^2+1\Biggl)$$

$$ = \Biggl(\sum \limits_{k=n+1}^{2n} 3(k^2-1)+n + 5(k-n)^2+1\Biggl)$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\left(3\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} (k^2-1)\right) + \left(5\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n} (k-n)^2+1\right)&=\left(3\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} k^2-1\right) + \left(5\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^2+1\right) \\
&=3\left(\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} k^2\right)-3n + 5\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^2\right)+5n \\
&=\left(8\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} k^2\right)+2n 
\end{align}

Comment: How did you change the the lower limit from n+1 to 1 in the second sum?

Comment: See the answer from @PythonSage, he explains it very well

Answer (score 1):

$\left(3\sum\limits_{1}^{n}(k^2-1)\right)+\left(5\sum\limits_{n+1}^{2n}(k-n)^2+1\right)$
Note that for $k=\{n+1,n+2,\cdots2n\}, k-n=\{1,2,\cdots n\}$. Hence, the sum can be rewritten as
$\left(3\sum\limits_{1}^{n}(k^2-1)\right)+\left(5\sum\limits_{1}^{n}(j)^2+1\right)=8\sum\limits_{1}^{n}k^2+2n$.

Comment: How did you change the lower limit to 1 in the second sum? you just did j = k-n?

Comment: The +1 is also included in the summation

Comment: $j$ varies from $1$ to $n$ as well. The key idea is that a variable varies from $1$ to $n$. You can write it as $j,k,x,y,z$ right? Hence, we can write both $j$ and $k$ as $k$. Hope that clears your confusion

Comment: @user325 Edited.

Comment: See [here](http://blogs.ubc.ca/infiniteseriesmodule/units/unit-1/sigma-notation/changing-summation-limits/) for info on changing the index of summation if you are unfamiliar with it

Comment: Oh I see now, the k-n can just be written as k because when you subtract k-n, the lower limit automatically changes to 1 and the upper limit automatically changes to n, which then would be the same thing as the first sum

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n 3(k - 1)^2 + \sum_{k = n + 1}^{2n} 5(k - n)^2 + 1$$
$$ = \sum_{k = 1}^n 3(k - 1)^2 + \sum_{k = 1}^{n} 5k^2 + 1$$
$$ = 1 + \frac{3n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6} + \frac{5n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
$$ = \frac{6 + n(3(2n^2 - 3n + 1) + 5(2n^2+3n+1))}{6}$$
$$ = \frac{8n^3+3n^2+4n + 3}{3}$$

Using the common sum $$\sum_{k = 1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$